# Fix web api method incorrect behavior

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-web-api

I have an issue in my api method. I have a method GetDrones which is not working correctly (there is no adequate logic here. I've just made it as short as I could to make it simplier) [way 0]:

```
[Produces("application/json")]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class OwnersController : Controller
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
    private readonly ClaimsPrincipal _caller;

    public OwnersController(ApplicationDbContext context, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _context = context;
        _caller = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User;

    }
    [HttpGet("GetOwnersDrones")]
    public List<Drone> GetDrones()
    {
        var userId = _caller.Claims.Single(c => c.Type == "id");
        var customer = _context.Customers.Single(c => c.Identity.Id == userId.Value);
        var owner = _context.Owners.Single(o => o.CustomerId == customer.Id);


        return _context.Drones.ToList();
    }
}
```

[image]
[image]
But if I change the method this way [way 1]:

```
[HttpGet("GetOwnersDrones")]
public List<Drone> GetDrones()
{
    var userId = _caller.Claims.Single(c => c.Type == "id");
    var customer = _context.Customers.Single(c => c.Identity.Id == userId.Value);
    var owner = _context.Owners.Single(o => o.CustomerId == customer.Id);


    return null;
}
```

[image]
Or that way [way 2]:

```
[HttpGet("GetOwnersDrones")]
public List<Drone> GetDrones()
{
    var userId = _caller.Claims.Single(c => c.Type == "id");
    var customer = _context.Customers.Single(c => c.Identity.Id == userId.Value);
    //var owner = _context.Owners.Single(o => o.CustomerId == customer.Id);


    return _context.Drones.ToList();
}
```

[image]
Both are working (no error pops up). Thus, I conclude that

```
_context.Drones.ToList();
```

and

```
_context.Owners.Single(o => o.CustomerId == customer.Id);
```

doesn't work when in one method? How can I resolve this and make the primordial method work?

**UPDATE**

```
[HttpGet("GetOwnersDrones")]
public Owner GetOwnersDrones()
{
    var userId = _caller.Claims.Single(c => c.Type == "id");
    var customer = _context.Customers.Single(c => c.Identity.Id == userId.Value);
    var owner = _context.Owners.SingleOrDefault(o => o.CustomerId == customer.Id);

    return owner;
}
```

[image]

**DEBUG**
I've debuged through the method. As you can see the `drones` list and `owner` is not empty but still I recieve 'Could not get any response'
[image]

Comment: Have you tried with URL: **https://localhost:44335/api/owners/GetDrones**  As you do not have action method called **GetOwnersDrones**

Comment: @PrasadTelkikar Yes I have, it's a typo

Comment: Can you provide us your routing template

Comment: @PrasadTelkikar I am not sure what are you asking about. Do you mean these routes: ```[HttpGet("GetOwnersDrones")]```? I think the routes are valid because I can get the result if I change the method like in [way 2] (I've added a screenshot)

Comment: What are you expecting from action method [way 1]. If you want any output in json format then you need to return something

Comment: @PrasadTelkikar I expect null and I got null in a response. Which shows that error is not in ```_context.Owners.Single(o => o.CustomerId == customer.Id);``` Then I make second test [way 2] which shows that error is not in ```_context.Drones.ToList()```. So that where the error is? Or why doesn't the first method aka [way 0] work?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192859/discussion-between-prasad-telkikar-and-storm).

Comment: Debugging while attaching to the IIS process will show you the exact error that is thrown in the server that will tell you everything you need to know..

Comment: The problem is probably the Single method throwing an exception.
Try using SingleOrDefault to make sure to receive null instead of an error when the query returns no matches

Comment: @AviMeltser I've tried SingelOrDefault, First, FirstOrDefault and none of these worked. Trying to debug it now

Comment: You are expected to debug your code before posting on Stackoverflow.

Comment: why are you not debugging your own code rather than try to guess what may or may not happen? Put a breakpoint in your API method, step through the code and see where the problem is.

Comment: @AndreiDragotoniu I've debuged the method but still I don't know what I need to see here. Everything in the method is working but 'Could not get any response' is returned. I've added debug screenshot to the post

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that this line:

```
    var owner = _context.Owners.Single(o => o.CustomerId == customer.Id);
```

did not find any matches for the query and threw an exception.
I would recommend reading about LINQ's *Single* and *SingleOrDefault* methods to understand their behavior better.

By not debugging your code (check out [Attacking To Process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/attach-to-running-processes-with-the-visual-studio-debugger?view=vs-2019) to debug Web API services) you miss all the necessary information you need in order to resolve your issues.

You have to pay attention to the exceptions thrown in the controller.

Comment: So why doen't it find any mathes while there are owners in the database? I've updated the post for you

Comment: I don't know your database but you seem to contradict yourself because your update does show matching results to the query.

Comment: You said that the query could not find the owner in the db. I disproved it by showing you that the query is working and returns an owner. Did I understand you correctly?

Comment: Having posted only part of your code, I can't tell the original source of the error you are getting and have commented on the code that you have attached.
According to the code, you attached the Single method seemed to be throwing an error. However, only you can tell what the real error is since the code posted is only partial and because you have to debug your code to understand where the exception is thrown and what the problem is

Comment: @Storm if `_context.Owners.Single(o => o.CustomerId == customer.Id);` is throwing exception it means that there are multiple Owner records for given customer id. `Single` method works if there is only one element is returned by predicate. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.single?view=netframework-4.8